# How to embed this circle tangent to the other circles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

I want to construct a circle that would be tangent to the $3$ circles and would have its diameter lie somewhere on the segment $BI$.

$EF$ includes the diameters of the $3$ given circles. $EB=BF$.

What do you think is the best way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use circular inversion, or just intersect the segment $BI$ with the hyperbola that is the locus of points $P$ for which $PG-PI=BG$. That intersection is the center of the circle you are looking for.

If you are familiar with the [Descartes circle theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesCircleTheorem.html), you know in advance the radius $r$ of your circle, since, given that $BG=1$,
$$2\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{r^2}\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{r}\right)^2$$
must hold, hence $r=\frac{2}{3}$.

By inverting the construction with respect to a circle with center $E$ and radius $EB$, we just have to find a circle that is tangent to two parallel lines and an inner tangent circle, then take its circular inverse:

[image: Circular inversion]

Comment: Well, I couldn't construct such a hyperbola, could I? And so could you elaborate about the inversion? I am not too familiar with this transformation and hence not sure how I would go about using it for this. thanks.

Comment: I would take a circular inversion with respect to a circle with center $I$ and radius $IG$, in order to have a similar problem with a straight line and two circles; or take a circular inversion with respect to a circle with center $E$ and radius $EB$ in order to have a similar problem with two straight lines and a circle. However, notice that the http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesCircleTheorem.html gives you the answer in advance.

Comment: Anyway, I added the solution with straightedge and compass through circular inversion.